# ViewComponent not found in Asp.NET Core 2.2 using Razor Pages

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have created a very simple view component (`/ViewComponents/MenuViewComponent.cs`):

```
namespace MySite.ViewComponents
{    
    public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult((IViewComponentResult)View("Default"));
        }
    }
}
```

The view part is here (`/Pages/Components/Menu/Default.cshtml`):

```
<div>Menu</div>
```

I am invoking the *Menu* from the `_Layout.cshtml` file like this:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MenuViewComponent");
```

When viewing a page I get the following error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'MenuViewComponent' could not be found.
A view component must be a public non-abstract class, not contain any generic parameters, 
and either be decorated with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the 'ViewComponent' suffix. 
A view component must not be decorated with 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.
```

**Question**:
What am I missing to get this working?

Comment: Reference [View components in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Make sure component view is in the search path and also when calling just use the name without the suffix `@await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")`

Comment: @Nkosi I tried moving the files around to match the recommendations from your link, but nothing worked. BUT your suggestion to just invoke using "Menu" was the solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure component view is in the search path as described in the following

Reference [View components in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

and also when calling the component just use the name without the suffix

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
```